# Android:: List View : Runtime error

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my logcat:

```
04-28 08:23:03.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ListViewActivity.fetchItems(ListViewActivity.java:59)
        at com.example.ListViewActivity.onCreate(ListViewActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        ... 11 more
04-28 08:23:03.353: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Force finishing activity com.example/.ListViewActivity
04-28 08:23:03.383: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Force finishing activity com.example/.Search
04-28 08:23:04.193: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45078198 com.example/.ListViewActivity}
04-28 08:23:10.074: INFO/Process(326): Sending signal. PID: 326 SIG: 9
04-28 08:23:10.304: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.example (pid 326) has died.
04-28 08:23:10.333: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{4506ec60 com.example/com.example.Search paused=true}
04-28 08:23:10.353: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{45067e78 com.example/com.example.Login paused=false}
04-28 08:23:10.364: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{450680e8 com.example/com.example.RolesActivity paused=false}
04-28 08:23:10.644: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Start proc com.example for activity com.example/.Login: pid=334 uid=10032 gids={3003, 1015}
04-28 08:23:11.613: INFO/UsageStats(68): Unexpected resume of com.example while already resumed in com.example
04-28 08:23:12.323: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-28 08:23:13.183: WARN/InputManagerService(68): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 326 uid 10032
04-28 08:23:13.663: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed activity com.example/.Login: 3288 ms (total 11282 ms)
04-28 08:23:14.034: INFO/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x2cefd8:0x2cf0e4] in 2295893 ns
04-28 08:23:19.484: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{450747c8 com.example/.Search}
04-28 08:23:19.484: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45078198 com.example/.ListViewActivity}
04-28 08:23:41.144: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-28 08:28:41.164: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-28 08:33:41.193: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-28 08:38:41.213: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-28 08:43:41.223: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-28 08:48:41.294: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Plzz help me out with this...

Comment: Post some code also so that we can understand what actually you are doing...

Answer (score 2):

For your activity your extending which one Activity or ListActivity, checkout the problem may come with this also, if possible  post your code ....